# How to horizontally center a div inside its parent while overflowing the parent?

Tags: html, css, css-position

The parent has a percentage width. I'm looking for a simple way to keep the child div: `.wrp` centered in it's parent: `.contr` even when it overflows the parent or even overflowing the page. I tried absolute positioning but it doesn't seem to work here.

**Example:**

[image]

Ideas?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contr {                                                 /* << contr = Container */
  width: 40%;
  height: 95%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrp {                                                       /* << wrp = Wrapper */
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.expand {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes expand {
  50% {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    @import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: 1px solid #555;
    }
    
    .v-cntr {                               /* << v-cntr = Vertically Centered */
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY( -50% );
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contr v-cntr">        
    <div class="wrp v-cntr expand">
      stay<br>centered in<br>parent
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Edit: To clarify I want the child div to overflow it's parent**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `position: absolute` with `left:50%` and `translateX(-50%)`:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contr {                                                 /* << contr = Container */
  height: 95%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrp {                                                       /* << wrp = Wrapper */
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.expand {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes expand {
  50% {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}

/*new*/  


.wrp.v-cntr {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    @import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: 1px solid #555;
    }
    
    .v-cntr {                               /* << v-cntr = Vertically Centered */
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY( -50% );
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contr v-cntr">        
    <div class="wrp v-cntr expand">
      stay<br>centered in<br>parent
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is centering the parent div now. I want the parent div to stay left aligned where it is at.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the DIV to expand past the edge of the parent's bounds at all, what you're looking for is to set `max-width: 100%` on `.v-cntr`:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contr {                                                 /* << contr = Container */
  height: 95%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.wrp {                                                       /* << wrp = Wrapper */
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.expand {
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes expand {
  50% {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    @import url( 'https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css' );
    
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: 1px solid #555;
    }
    
    .v-cntr {                               /* << v-cntr = Vertically Centered */
      max-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY( -50% );
    }
    
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contr v-cntr">        
    <div class="wrp v-cntr expand">
      stay<br>centered in<br>parent
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This would work. Only if it overflowed like in the sample picture I showed. This is a good attempt but because `max-width` is at `100%` it eliminates the child div from ever overflowing the container. I want overflow to happen and for it to be visible.

Comment: You could make it overlow with the box itself centered by setting the `left` on `.contr` and `.expand` respectively, though that would make it start on the left, and 'expand' to be centralised. I don't think it's possible to center a dynamically-expanding overflowing element at all times without jQuery.

Comment: There must be a way with absolute positioning maybe.